Creative Calculus Proof that I can't manage
I was working on a Calculus problem set that was supposedly very challenging, and indeed it was, as the first problem I was already stuck on. Here it is:
Prove that $e^{\pi}$ > ${\pi}^{e}$. The hint was to find a suitable function with the essential properties that yield the inequality.
I took the natural log of both sides and got ${\pi}$ * ln(e) = e * ln(${\pi}$). I managed more algebraic manipulation and tried some limits, but nothing has gotten me even remotely close. I don't need an answer; I need a nudge in the right direction.
Also, if my formatting sucks, comment on that, and feel free to edit and correct the post.

Well, you know what $\ln(e)$ is

Yes, that was part of the algebraic manipulation I did.

By the way, the equals sign does not belong there since the two sides are not equal

are you allowed to take derivatives?

If you denote $f(x) = x^{\frac1{x}}$ then it is sufficient to compare $f(\pi)$ and $f(e)$ which should be manageable by calculus.

Your problem is equivalent to proving that $\frac{\ln\pi}{\pi} < \frac{\ln e}{e}$, that is why you may study the function $\frac{\ln x}{x}$, which turns out to reach its maximum at $x = e$.
